# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array of strings called `Events` that I'm trying to concatenate to a string and then put it in my html using a jQuery method.

```
     output+='<li><a href="#" '+'onmouseup="controlMap('+Events[i]+')">'+Events[i]+'</a></li>';//gives an error   
 document.getElementById("myUL").innerHTML = output;
```

However, keep geting the following error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

The brackets seem fine to me but I'm not sure about the syntax

ps: the loop works fine when I use this statment :

```
output+='<li><a href="#">'+Events[i]+'</a></li>';
   document.getElementById("myUL").innerHTML = output;
```

but as soon as I replace it with the code up there I start getting the error.

Comment: Works [just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/bjm2Ljr5/), there's something coming before the posted code, that has an opening parentheses, that you're not showing us.

Comment: send the entire loop. error is somewhere else

Comment: I think the error is from Events[i] or output no the code itself

Comment: What's the value of Events[i]?

Comment: @airos if theres no Event it would say *Cannot get i of undefined* , if theres an Event property it would work, so no thats not a problem

Comment: @Jonasw Wouldn't that be assuming that `Events[i]` is an integer and not a string? Who knows what's in `Events[i]` I personally think that it is impossible  to say with the information we have

Comment: Events is an array of strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error basically will happen when you have a delimiter in your `Events` array that indicates the end of a statement, like if I have the following array of Events, I am expecting that with your code these errors would occur

```
var Events = [
  '0', // this will work
  'ThisIsATest', // will fail with ThisIsATest is undefined
  'This is a test' // will fail due to missing ) after the statement
];
```

`0` is fine, it will print `0`, `ThisIsATest` would work but only if a global variable exist that is called exactly that, and `This is a test` would fail with the error specified that a `)` is missing.

The reason for the error is how you handle adding the argument to your function. If it gets turned into real html your function doesn't have any `'` surrounding it, so  it is not seen as a string value, but it looks like it's referring to a variable. If a space comes then the JavaScript engine rather expects that your function should end, or be followed by a `,` to indicate the next argument or should be followed by a `)`

To handle it more correctly, you either escape the outer quotes inside your script (since you started with single quotes, escape the single quote), like so

```
content += '<li><a href="#" onmouseup="clickedMe(\'' + Events[i] + '\')">' + Events[i] + '</a></li>';
```

or, use the index of the event, and add a new function that simply handles your index by forwarding it to the "real" handler of that function, like so

```
content += '<li><a href="#" onmouseup="clickedMyIndex(' + i + ')">' + Events[i] + '</a></li>';

// ... and then a bit later ...

function clickedMyIndex( index ) {
  clickedMe(Events[index]);
}
```

The example here will reproduce your original error and also show 2 possible solutions in fixing them (a third one would be not to use string concatination, but I guess this already shows you what you need to know)

```js
var Events = [
  '0', // this will work
  'ThisIsATest', // will fail with ThisIsATest is undefined
  'This is a test' // will fail due to missing ) after the statement
];

function fillIncorrect() {
  let target = document.querySelector('#incorrectHandling'), i, content = '<ul>';
  for (i = 0; i < Events.length; i++) {
    content += '<li><a href="#" onmouseup="clickedMe(' + Events[i] + ')">' + Events[i] + '</a></li>';
  }
  content += '</ul>';
  target.innerHTML = content;
}

function fillCorrect1() {
  let target = document.querySelector('#correctHandling1'), i, content = '<ul>';
  for (i = 0; i < Events.length; i++) {
    content += '<li><a href="#" onmouseup="clickedMe(\'' + Events[i] + '\')">' + Events[i] + '</a></li>';
  }
  content += '</ul>';
  target.innerHTML = content;
}

function fillCorrect2() {
  let target = document.querySelector('#correctHandling2'), i, content = '<ul>';
  for (i = 0; i < Events.length; i++) {
    content += '<li><a href="#" onmouseup="clickedMyIndex(' + i + ')">' + Events[i] + '</a></li>';
  }
  content += '</ul>';
  target.innerHTML = content;
}

function clickedMe( text ) {
  alert('You clicked ' + text );
}

function clickedMyIndex( index ) {
  clickedMe(Events[index]);
}

fillIncorrect();
fillCorrect1();
fillCorrect2();
```

```html
<div id="incorrectHandling">
</div>

<div id="correctHandling1">
</div>

<div id="correctHandling2">
</div>
```